# 2 RAID Arrays on Z390 chipset (M.2x4 and SATA)

Tags: windows-10, ssd, raid, sata, m.2

I need to know if this is possible. To have two RAID arrays on a z390 platform. The first being a boot drive composed of two M.2x4 pcie SSDs in RAID 1 and the other being composed of two SATA III SSDs in RAID 0.

The ASRock Z390 Taichi Ultimate appears like it might support this since two of the M.2 ports are pcie style, and if both are used it still leaves two open SATA III ports on the Intel controller.

1. If the M.2 pcie disks are configured in RAID, can I use these two extra SATA III ports for another RAID array?
2. If question one is possible, can I use the M.2 array as my boot drive?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. I have successfully built a Z390 based machine with both an M.2 RAID 1 array (boot) and SATA RAID 0 array (D disk), all running off of the Z390 chipset Intel controller. Creating the RAID arrays is standard, and not significantly different than with just SATA disks. The primary difference being that the M.2 disks must have "RST PCIe Storage Remapping" Enabled.

This system is configured as such:

- i9 9900k
- ASRock Z390 Taichi Ultimate
- 2x 1TB Samsung 970 EVO M.2 SSDs (RAID 1 + Boot)
- 2x 1TB WD Blue SSDs (RAID 0)